# How to make Sort Icon visible for Angular UI grid when column is resized to and text shows ellipsis?

Tags: css, angular-ui-grid

I want the sort icon to be visible (when column is sorted) after the ellipsis whenever the header is resized

Something like this,

[image]

I have tried to target the span element under

> `.ui-cell-contents`

and tried various combinations, but all in vain. I am sure this is not something complex, but just could not figure it out.

Can someone kindly throw let me know how to achieve the same ?

Here is the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zzUDslrm7AVAeTB92nkX?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the icon element is inline, it will behave like text and be ellipsised off. You simply need to take it out of the normal flow. You can add `position:absolute` to the icon and play with it from there.

```
.ui-grid-cell-contents i.ui-grid-icon-up-dir,
.ui-grid-cell-contents i.ui-grid-icon-down-dir{
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you'll probably want to add some padding to the right of the heading when it's sorted so the that icon is not overlapping text. You'll probably need to play with the styles a bit, but this will at least make it visible for you.

Comment: I guess what you  suggested is a good solution. Let me try with this and get back to you.

Comment: I did check this. So far it works but need to play around with the styling.. thanks for the info!